# Pass array of data to form

Tags: symfony

I'm using symfony and I need to pass two arrays so I can make a selectable list.

For now in form builder I have this:

```
    ->add('city', EntityType::class, [
        'label' => 'Select city',
        'class' => Cities::class,
        'choice_label' => 'title',
        'choice_value' => 'title'
    ])
```

It throws me all `cities` in the list. I want to filtrate them. I've done filtration on my controller like this:

```
    $capitals = $cityRepository->findBy(['cityType' => CityType::capital()->id()]);
    $villages = $cityRepository->findBy(['villageType' => CityType::village()->id()]);
```

this returns me two arrays: `capitals` and `villages`.

How can I pass them to the form ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your controller :

```
$form=$this->createForm(YourFormType::class, $yourEntity, array(
    'capitals'=>$capitals,
    'villages'=>$villages
));
```

In your form :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    /** @var array $capitals */
    $capitals=$options['capitals'];
    /** @var array $villages */
    $villages=$options['villages'];

    $builder->add('city', EntityType::class, array(...)
            ->add('vallacap', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'mapped'=>false, //Make sure it's not mapped to any entity
                'choices'=>array(
                    'Capitals'=>$capitals,
                    'Villages'=>$villages
                ),
                'required'=>false,
            ));
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class'=>Personnalisation::class,
        'capitals'=>null, // Set default to null in case argument is not passed
        'villages'=>null,
    ));
}
```

Comment: Where to place `capitals` and `villages` ?

Comment: should capitals and village be in the same select? or two différent select?

Comment: In the same, but in the list there should be bold Cities and bold Villages words.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't make sense, where do Universites and Colleges come from? Not in your question

Comment: Edited, my bad.

Comment: So, you mean you want something like a `<select>` with one `<optgroup>` having 'Cities' as label, and all cities inside, and a second `<optgroup>` with 'Capitals' as label, and all capitals inside? Is that right?

Comment: Exactly like you said :)

Comment: Just edited my answer anyway @zlotte... That should be what you need

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass the arrays to `choices` option.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-choices

```php
    ->add('city', EntityType::class, [
        'label' => 'Select city',
        'class' => Cities::class,
        'choice_label' => 'title',
        'choice_value' => 'title',
        'choices' => $choices // ------------> This line
    ])
```

`$choices = array_merge($capitals, $villages);`

Comment: from where `$choices` came to the form builder ?